Exception encountered when calling layer "tf.scatter_nd" (type TFOpLambda)
I am trying to write the code for the ghost Unet architecture for image segmentation and it keeps on giving me the above error. I have no idea how to proceed ahead and fix this error.
Here is the code for the architecture and the functions related to it
def ghost_module(inputs, input_size, output_size, kernel_size, ratio, dw_size, stride, relu_func):
    # Create two initial and new channels based on input and output size
    initial_channel_size = output_size // ratio
    new_channel_size = initial_channel_size

    # Primary Conv
    x1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(initial_channel_size, kernel_size, strides=stride, padding='same', use_bias=False)(inputs)
    x1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x1)
    x1 = relu_func(x1)

    # Cheap Conv
    x2 = tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D(dw_size, strides=1, padding='same', use_bias=False)(x1)
    x2 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x2)
    x2 = relu_func(x2)
    x2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(new_channel_size, 1, strides=1, padding='same', use_bias=False)(x2)

    # Concatenate primary and cheap conv outputs
    out = tf.concat([x1, x2], axis=-1)

    return out


def squeeze_excite_block(inputs, ratio=16):
    channels = inputs.shape[-1]

    squeeze = tf.reduce_mean(inputs, axis=[1, 2], keepdims=True)
    excitation = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=channels // ratio, activation='relu')(squeeze)
    excitation = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=channels, activation='sigmoid')(excitation)
    outputs = inputs * excitation
    return outputs


def unmax_pool(inputs, pool_size, strides):
    batch_size, height, width, channels = inputs.shape

    stride_height, stride_width = strides

    # Adjust height and width to be divisible by strides
    padded_height = (height + stride_height - 1) // stride_height * stride_height
    padded_width = (width + stride_width - 1) // stride_width * stride_width

    # Pad the input tensor if necessary
    if padded_height > height or padded_width > width:
        paddings = [(0, 0), (0, padded_height - height), (0, padded_width - width), (0, 0)]
        inputs = tf.pad(inputs, paddings)

    # Reshape the input tensor
    if batch_size is None:
        inputs_flat = tf.reshape(inputs, [-1, padded_height // stride_height, stride_height, padded_width // stride_width, stride_width, channels])
    else:
        inputs_flat = tf.reshape(inputs, [batch_size, padded_height // stride_height, stride_height, padded_width // stride_width, stride_width, channels])

    inputs_flat = tf.transpose(inputs_flat, [0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5])
    inputs_flat = tf.reshape(inputs_flat, [batch_size if batch_size is not None else -1, padded_height // stride_height, padded_width // stride_width, stride_height * stride_width * channels])

    # Calculate the indices of the maximum values in the original input tensor
    max_indices = tf.argmax(inputs_flat, axis=3, output_type=tf.int64)
    max_indices = tf.reshape(max_indices, [-1])  # Flatten the max_indices tensor

    # Unravel the maximum indices into the output tensor
    unraveled_indices = tf.stack([
        tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.range(height, dtype=tf.int64), [width]), [-1]),
        tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.range(width, dtype=tf.int64) * stride_width, [height]), [-1]),
        max_indices
    ], axis=-1)

    updates = tf.ones_like(max_indices, dtype=inputs.dtype)
    updates = tf.reshape(updates, [-1, 1, 1, 1])

    unmapped_flat = tf.scatter_nd(unraveled_indices, updates, [batch_size if batch_size is not None else -1, padded_height, padded_width, channels])

    # Remove padding if necessary
    if padded_height > height or padded_width > width:
        unmapped_flat = unmapped_flat[:, :height, :width, :]

    return unmapped_flat


def double_conv(inputs, filters, kernel_size, padding='same', activation='relu'):
   
    # First convolution layer
    conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding=padding, activation=activation)(inputs)
    conv1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv1)

    # Second convolution layer
    conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding=padding, activation=activation)(conv1)
    conv2 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv2)

    return conv2

def transpose_conv(inputs, filters, kernel_size, strides, padding='same'):
    batch_size, height, width, channels = inputs.shape
    output_height = height * strides
    output_width = width * strides
    
    transpose_conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
        filters=filters,
        kernel_size=kernel_size,
        strides=strides,
        padding=padding,
        use_bias=False
    )
    
    # Calculate padding to ensure output size matches expected size
    padding_h = (output_height - height) // 2
    padding_w = (output_width - width) // 2
    
    # Apply transpose convolution
    outputs = transpose_conv(inputs)
    
    # Apply cropping to match expected size
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Cropping2D(cropping=((padding_h, padding_h), (padding_w, padding_w)))(outputs)
    
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(outputs)

    return outputs

def concatenate_layer(inputs, axis=-1):
    # Get the shapes of the input tensors
    shapes = [input_tensor.shape.as_list() for input_tensor in inputs]
    
    # Determine the maximum height and width among the tensors
    max_height = max(shape[1] for shape in shapes)
    max_width = max(shape[2] for shape in shapes)
    
    # Pad or crop the tensors to match the maximum height and width
    processed_inputs = []
    for input_tensor, shape in zip(inputs, shapes):
        height_pad = max_height - shape[1]
        width_pad = max_width - shape[2]
        paddings = [(0, 0), (0, height_pad), (0, width_pad), (0, 0)]
        processed_input = tf.pad(input_tensor, paddings) if height_pad > 0 or width_pad > 0 else input_tensor
        processed_inputs.append(processed_input)
    
    # Concatenate the processed tensors
    return tf.concat(processed_inputs, axis=axis)

def GhostUNet(input_shape, num_classes):
    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)

    # Encoder
    gm1 =  ghost_module(inputs, input_size=3, output_size=64, kernel_size=3, ratio=2, dw_size=3, stride=1, relu_func=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
    dw1 =  tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D(3, strides=1, padding='same', use_bias=False)(gm1)
    gm1 =  ghost_module(dw1, input_size=3, output_size=64, kernel_size=3, ratio=2, dw_size=3, stride=1, relu_func=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
    pool1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(gm1)
    
    gm2 =  ghost_module(pool1, input_size=3, output_size=64, kernel_size=3, ratio=2, dw_size=3, stride=1, relu_func=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
    dw2 =  tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D(3, strides=1, padding='same', use_bias=False)(gm2)
    se1 = squeeze_excite_block(inputs, 64)
    gm2 =  ghost_module(se1, input_size=3, output_size=64, kernel_size=3, ratio=2, dw_size=3, stride=1, relu_func=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
    pool2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(gm2)

    gm3 =  ghost_module(pool2, input_size=3, output_size=64, kernel_size=3, ratio=2, dw_size=3, stride=1, relu_func=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
    dw3 =  tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D(3, strides=1, padding='same', use_bias=False)(gm3)
    gm3 =  ghost_module(dw3, input_size=3, output_size=64, kernel_size=3, ratio=2, dw_size=3, stride=1, relu_func=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
    pool3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(gm3)

    gm4 =  ghost_module(pool3, input_size=3, output_size=64, kernel_size=3, ratio=2, dw_size=3, stride=1, relu_func=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
    dw4 =  tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D(3, strides=1, padding='same', use_bias=False)(gm4)
    se2 = squeeze_excite_block(dw4, 64)
    gm4 =  ghost_module(se2, input_size=3, output_size=64, kernel_size=3, ratio=2, dw_size=3, stride=1, relu_func=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
    pool4 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(gm4)

    gm5 =  ghost_module(pool4, input_size=3, output_size=64, kernel_size=3, ratio=2, dw_size=3, stride=1, relu_func=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
    dw5 =  tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D(3, strides=1, padding='same', use_bias=False)(gm5)
    gm5 =  ghost_module(dw5, input_size=3, output_size=64, kernel_size=3, ratio=2, dw_size=3, stride=1, relu_func=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
    pool5 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(gm5)

    gm6 =  ghost_module(pool5, input_size=3, output_size=64, kernel_size=3, ratio=2, dw_size=3, stride=1, relu_func=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
    dw6 =  tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D(3, strides=1, padding='same', use_bias=False)(gm6)
    se3 = squeeze_excite_block(dw6, 64)
    gm6 =  ghost_module(se3, input_size=3, output_size=64, kernel_size=3, ratio=2, dw_size=3, stride=1, relu_func=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
    pool6 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(gm6)

    gm7 =  ghost_module(pool6, input_size=3, output_size=64, kernel_size=3, ratio=2, dw_size=3, stride=1, relu_func=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
    dw7 =  tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D(3, strides=1, padding='same', use_bias=False)(gm7)
    gm7 =  ghost_module(dw7, input_size=3, output_size=64, kernel_size=3, ratio=2, dw_size=3, stride=1, relu_func=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
    pool7 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(gm7)
    print(pool7.shape)

    unmaxpool = unmax_pool(pool7, pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2))

    # Decoder 
    up1 = transpose_conv(pool7, filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=1)
    dconv1 = double_conv(up1, filters=64, kernel_size=3)
    concat1 = concatenate_layer([dconv1, pool6])

    up2 = transpose_conv(concat1, filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=1)
    dconv2 = double_conv(up2, filters=64, kernel_size=3)
    concat2 = concatenate_layer([dconv2, pool4])

    up3 = transpose_conv(concat2, filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=1)
    dconv3 = double_conv(up3, filters=64, kernel_size=3)
    concat3 = concatenate_layer([dconv3, pool3])

    up4 = transpose_conv(concat3, filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=1)
    dconv4 = double_conv(up3, filters=64, kernel_size=3)
    concat4 = concatenate_layer([dconv4, pool2])

    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(num_classes, (1, 1), activation='softmax')(concat3)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

    return model


Here is the description for the unmax pool function which seems to be causing the error:
Here's a breakdown of the function:
Inputs:
    inputs: Input tensor, typically the output of a max-pooling operation.
    pool_size: Size of the pooling window, usually represented as a tuple (height, width).
    strides: Stride of the pooling operation, also represented as a tuple (stride_height, stride_width).

Variable Initialization:
    Extracts the dimensions of the input tensor: batch_size, height, width, and channels.

Padding Adjustment:
    Adjusts the height and width of the input tensor to be divisible by the specified strides.
    If padding is necessary, pads the input tensor accordingly.

Reshaping:
    Reshapes the input tensor to prepare it for unraveling the max-pooled indices.
    The input tensor is reshaped into a flattened form that divides the height and width by the stride values.

Index Calculation:
    Calculates the indices of the maximum values in the original input tensor.
    Uses tf.argmax to find the indices of the maximum values along the appropriate axis.

Index Unraveling:
    Unravels the maximum indices into the output tensor.
    Constructs the indices of the maximum values in the original input tensor.

Updates Construction:
    Constructs an update tensor filled with ones with the same data type as the input tensor.

Scatter Update:
    Uses tf.scatter_nd to scatter the updates into the output tensor based on the unraveled indices.
    This operation effectively "unpools" the max-pooled indices back into the output tensor.

Padding Removal:
    Removes any padding that was added earlier, restoring the output tensor to its original size.

Output:
    Returns the resulting tensor, which represents the unpooled version of the input tensor.

Overall, the unmax_pool function takes a max-pooled tensor as input and reconstructs the unpooled version of the tensor, effectively performing the inverse operation of max pooling. This function is commonly used in decoder parts of neural networks to restore spatial information lost during max pooling operations in the encoder.
And here is the error extract


ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 3
      1 input_shape = (96, 128, 3)  # Example input shape
      2 num_classes = 66  # Example number of classes
----> 3 model = GhostUNet(input_shape, num_classes)

Cell In[9], line 44, in GhostUNet(input_shape, num_classes)
     41 pool7 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(gm7)
     42 print(pool7.shape)
---> 44 unmaxpool = unmax_pool(pool7, pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2))
     46 # Decoder 
     47 up1 = transpose_conv(pool7, filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=1)

Cell In[8], line 70, in unmax_pool(inputs, pool_size, strides)
     67 updates = tf.ones_like(max_indices, dtype=inputs.dtype)
     68 updates = tf.reshape(updates, [-1, 1, 1, 1])
---> 70 unmapped_flat = tf.scatter_nd(unraveled_indices, updates, [batch_size if batch_size is not None else -1, padded_height, padded_width, channels])
     72 # Remove padding if necessary
     73 if padded_height > height or padded_width > width:

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py:9178, in scatter_nd(indices, updates, shape, name)
   9176   pass  # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
   9177 except (TypeError, ValueError):
-> 9178   _result = _dispatch.dispatch(
   9179         scatter_nd, (), dict(indices=indices, updates=updates,
   9180                              shape=shape, name=name)
   9181       )
   9182   if _result is not _dispatch.OpDispatcher.NOT_SUPPORTED:
   9183     return _result

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:167, in dispatch(op, args, kwargs)
    165     return result
    166 for dispatcher in _GLOBAL_DISPATCHERS:
--> 167   result = dispatcher.handle(op, args, kwargs)
    168   if result is not OpDispatcher.NOT_SUPPORTED:
    169     return result

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\layers\core\tf_op_layer.py:119, in KerasOpDispatcher.handle(self, op, args, kwargs)
    114 """Handle the specified operation with the specified arguments."""
    115 if any(
    116     isinstance(x, keras_tensor.KerasTensor)
    117     for x in tf.nest.flatten([args, kwargs])
    118 ):
--> 119     return TFOpLambda(op)(*args, **kwargs)
    120 else:
    121     return self.NOT_SUPPORTED

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:1969, in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def, extract_traceback)
   1966   c_op = pywrap_tf_session.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
   1967 except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
   1968   # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
-> 1969   raise ValueError(e.message)
   1971 # Record the current Python stack trace as the creating stacktrace of this
   1972 # TF_Operation.
   1973 if extract_traceback:

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "tf.scatter_nd" (type TFOpLambda).

Dimensions [3,4) of input[shape=[?,?,?,?]] = [?] must match dimensions [1,4) of updates[shape=[?,1,1,1]] = [1,1,1]: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 1 and 3 for '{{node tf.scatter_nd/ScatterNd}} = ScatterNd[T=DT_FLOAT, Tindices=DT_INT64](Placeholder, Placeholder_1, tf.scatter_nd/ScatterNd/shape)' with input shapes: [2,3], [?,1,1,1], [4].

Call arguments received by layer "tf.scatter_nd" (type TFOpLambda):
  • indices=tf.Tensor(shape=(2, 3), dtype=int64)
  • updates=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1, 1, 1), dtype=float32)
  • shape=['-1', '2', '2', '64']
  • name=None

Here's a breakdown of the error:
The dimensions [3, 4) of the input tensor have an unknown shape represented by '?'. This tensor shape is [?,?,?,?].
The dimensions [1, 4) of the updates tensor have a shape of [?, 1, 1, 1].
The error message emphasizes that shapes must be of equal rank, but in this case, they are not. The rank of the input tensor shape is 1, while the rank of the updates tensor shape is 3.
The operation tf.scatter_nd/ScatterNd is being performed with the provided inputs. This operation is intended to perform scatter updates on an N-dimensional tensor.
The input arguments received by the layer tf.scatter_nd are as follows:
    Indices: A tensor of shape (2, 3) with data type int64.
    Updates: A tensor of shape (None, 1, 1, 1) with data type float32. The first dimension has an unknown size, indicated by 'None'.
    Shape: A list representing the desired shape of the output tensor, which is ['-1', '2', '2', '64'].
    Name: The name of the layer, which is currently set to None.

In summary, the error indicates a mismatch in shapes during the execution of the tf.scatter_nd operation, which is typically used for scatter updates on tensors. To resolve this issue, you may need to ensure that the dimensions of the input and updates tensors are compatible for the scatter operation being performed.
